# COMException accessing WMP from Plex Plugin (using Python for .NET)

Tags: python, .net, com, wmp, plex

### My Goal

I'm trying to create a plugin for [Plex Media Server (PMS)](https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/sections/200308733-Channel-Development) that will interface with WMP (Windows Media Player) to get metadata about Windows media library items.

### The Setup

- PMS uses Python 2.7 as its primary script host.  Plex Plugins are
  written in Python, though they operate in a sandboxed capacity. Unfortunately there's sad little documentation on what exactly the boundaries are on this sandboxed functionality.
- I decided to use Python for .NET to access the Windows SDK to interface with WMPLib. 
  Python for .NET (http://pythonnet.github.io/) is a Python
  library used to access functionality from .NET assemblies from within
  the Python runtime.
- I created a .NET assembly to access WMPLib, which
  is a part of the Windows SDK designed to programmatically access the
  functionality of WMP.  WMPLib is basically a COM Interop wrapper for
  .NET targeting wmp.dll.

### What's Working?

The whole chain from Python on through the COM-based WMP access is working.  If I fire up the embedded Plex Script Host that comes with Plex Media Server (a version of Python 2.7), I can readily access data from WMP.  That means that the following links in the chain are all working:

- Python *is* loading Python for .NET
- Python for .NET *is* loading my .NET assembly
- My .NET assembly *is* loading WMPLib (Interop.WMPLib.dll, a .NET assembly for COM Interop)
- WMPLib *is* successfully opening and utilizing wmp.dll (accessed from C:\Windows\System32)

### What's Not Working?

Activating the COM Interop part of this chain is *not* working from within the sandboxed Plex plugin.  Again, this plugin is written in standard Python, but something is subtly different about the Python execution environment once the sandboxing code has run.  I get the following exception when running the WMP access code from within the plugin:

```
COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D1327
   at WMPLib.IWMPPlayer4.get_mediaCollection()
```

- In this scenario I know that Python for .NET is working, because I've already loaded and accessed other things from my .NET assembly at this point.
- **C:\Windows\System32** is at the front of PATH variable.  I'm assuming that COM dlls should be located via the PATH environment variable ([This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa297182(v=vs.60).aspx) seems to say so), but I'm not entirely certain of that.  **How a COM assembly should be located in this unique scenario (Python accessing .NET accessing COM) is one of the biggest unknowns for me**.

### The Questions

1. How might the Plex plugin sandbox be changing the Python execution environment such that accessing the COM assembly is no longer working?
2. How should the COM assembly be located and accessed by the environment in this case?
3. Does it require specific permissions that the Plex sandbox may have locked down?

Maybe I should at least win some kind of prize for arriving at a question that intersects so many different technologies in a uniquely confusing way...

### Edit 1

I've ruled out any .NET related issues entirely, thanks to @Paulo's suggestion below.  I'm now doing all interop with `WMPLib` through the `comtypes` Python library.  Now I'm getting the following error:

```
COMError: (-1072884953, None, (None, None, None, 0, None))
```

Though `-1072884953` is a different error code, a little digging around makes it appear that this error is associated with (maybe equivalent to?) the same error that I was getting through .NET interop ([this post](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/614852-problem-opening-movies/#entry589151930) makes it appear so).

So now the facts that I'm stuck with are these:

1. `wmp.dll` is loading in all cases (which @Paulo helped me to figure
   out below).
2. When the code accessing WMP is run outside the Plex sandbox environment, library items can be accessed from WMP just fine.
3. When the code accessing WMP is run inside the Plex sandbox environment, library items cannot be accessed from WMP.
4. The error code that I get (whether from .NET or Python based COM interop is `NS_E_CURL_INVALIDPATH: The URL contains a path that is not valid.` This error appears to be involved with attempted playback in most cases.
5. This is odd because I've never gotten as far as playback in my scenario... I'm only attempting to call `wmp.mediaCollection`

So the Plex sandbox truly seems to be key in this scenario. Any further ideas?

### Edit 2

Minimally, this is the code that it takes to fail:

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject

wmp = CreateObject("{6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6}")
collection = wmp.mediaCollection
```

That `collection = wmp.mediaCollection` is where the error happens.

So there really aren't any parameters being passed in that could be causing the failure. To reiterate, this code runs fine in the general Python 2.7 context. It only fails within the Plex plugin sandbox. I don't know how to get details on how the Plex sandbox may be changing the execution environment. I'd imagine my answer lies in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Let me get this straight, and correct me if I'm wrong:

- You have a running instance of Python 2.7, Plex Media Server
- You're using a library, Python for .NET, to load a .NET into your process
- You're loading WMPLib, an imported COM interop assembly, in .NET to use the Windows Media Player library through Python for .NET

Let's clear this out:

- [`0xC00D1327` is `NS_E_CURL_INVALIDPATH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704587.aspx):

  > The URL contains a path that is not valid.

  It seems like a legitimate object error, not a COM error.
- The [DLL search order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) has little to do with it, since wmp.dll is registered with a full path under [InProcServer32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682390(v=vs.85).aspx) registry keys for each provided class, and that's what ultimately matters.

  In fact and as you stated, if you've reached this point, it's clearly not a problem about loading .NET assemblies or COM not finding a DLL.

Now, to the questions:

1. Since the error seems legit, you might not have access to the media collection (Internet zone?), or WMP is not correctly registered/installed, or some codec is missing or not correctly registered/installed, etc.

   What are you loading into WMP?  Try with basic things, such as local .WAV, .MP3, .AVI and .MPG files, then try more advanced formats e.g. MPEG4-encoded videos, or maybe remote locations.
2. You should attempt a more direct approach, although I can't really vouch which is better: [win32com (part of pywin32)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32) or [comtypes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/comtypes).

   It was a long while ago since I've looked at them, so take this with a grain of salt: with comtypes, you're able to use your COM objects much like regular Python objects with properties and methods, while win32com seems more inclined to do things by runtime name dispatching.

   At least you'll be punching something you really have to put up with (Python) instead of loading .NET for something that doesn't even require it (WMP).
3. I don't know what that sandboxing is about, but my guess is that it's a Python-only sandbox, not something that restricts usage of the operating system.

---

EDIT: Are you providing a filename (e.g. C:\path\to\file.mp4) where a URL is expected (file:///C:/path/to/file.mp4), or vice-versa?  I guess you must show the failing code and what values are being provided.

Comment: Your summary at the top is spot on. Great questions, great points. So it sounds like this isn't a problem with loading the COM assembly afterall. I'm embarrassed to admit it never occurred to me that the hex number with the COMException was an actual error code that I could find more on. Thanks for that. I get this error when I call getAll() on the IWMPMediaCollection from WMP, so it's not getting so far as actually streaming. But the items I'm pulling in do have a local file path, and I think you've got a good point about possibly not having access. I'll try some things and get back to you.

Comment: I find [Sysinternals Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) useful in diagnosing stuff like this.  It should be able to tell you if you hare hitting a permissions problem accessing a file (or registry setting.)

Comment: @Paulo Madeira, unfortunately I haven't been able to give this issue much attention over the last few days (we just gained a newborn). So, I haven't been able to try your suggestions yet. But I will be awarding you the bounty if I can't get to it before the bounty period is up. You have at least helped me to frame the problem better. Hopefully I'll get back to this soon...

Comment: Ok, no problem.  Oh, and congratulations! ;D

Comment: @PauloMadeira, edited my question with new info above. And thanks for the congrats!

Comment: @jdmcnair, I guess you have to show some code at this point.  It might be a filename (C:\...) vs URL (file:///C:/...) thing.

Comment: @PauloMadeira I just awarded you the bounty, though I don't think we quite got through to a complete answer. I went unresponsive for several days, and that didn't really give you the chance at the back and forth required for this sort of thing. I'm still very interested in any ideas you may have. Anyway, your answer was very helpful, and much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks.  Another thing you should look into is the security zone, or [library access in general](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563762(v=vs.85).aspx).